# Design pattern for interface for different classes

Tags: python, design-patterns, interface, class-method

I am seeking the right design pattern to implement interface in a class setting.

My file structure like follows:

1. **models:** which contains different models written in classes, say `Model`, `subModelA`, `subModelB`, `subsubModelC` etc.
2. **calculators:** which contains different calculator tools for each models. **Note the calculator will need to import model attributes for computation.**

My question is how should I structure my calculator file so as to follow the structure of models.

My original attempt is to write a `ABC` class for my `calculator` and then for each `subModel` class in **model** I write a respective **subCalculator** subclass to implement. However this does not seem to fully exploit the prescribed class structure in **model**.

Some baby example of my attempt:

```py
# in model.py

class model(object):
    def __init__(self,attr1):
        self.attr1 = attr1

class submodel(model):
    def __init__(self, attr1, attr2):
        super().__init__(attr1)
        self.attr2
```

```py
# in calculator.py
from model import model

class calculator(abc.ABC):
    @staticmethod
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def calculate(model):
        return model.attr1 ** 2

class subcalculator(calculator):
    def calculate(model):
        y = super(subcalculator, subcalculator).calculate(model)
        return y + model.attr2 ** 3
```

I have surveyed some design pattern catalogs as listed in [here](https://github.com/faif/python-patterns), and strategy seems to be the right pattern. But the baby example there does not address my concern, as I would hope to use class structure in model file.

I'd hope someone can give me a more full-fledged example in such case. My thanks in advance.

Comment: You should avoid parallel inheritance hierarchies. From the code that you posted it looks like the `calculate()` methods should be a method in the model.

Comment: @quamrana Yes. But is there any way to single out calculate method in a separate file so as to increase readability of my file. The real-life `calculate()` is a big mess so I want to single them out for the ease of maintaining the code in the future.

Answer (score 0):

So you can separate models and calculators like this:

```
# in model.py

import calculator as cal

class model(object):
    def __init__(self,attr1):
        self.attr1 = attr1
    def calculate(self):
        return cal.defaultCalc(self)

class submodel(model):
    def __init__(self, attr1, attr2):
        super().__init__(attr1)
        self.attr2
    def calculate(self):
        return cal.subCalc(self)

# in calculator.py

def defaultCalc(model):
    return model.attr1 ** 2

def subCalc(model):
    return defaultCalc(model) + model.attr2 ** 3
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I thought at start. But it seems in such case the interdependence between different `Calc` method in calculator.py are only revealed in the function. Is there a way to make that more obvious? (other than plainly commenting your code) Or is it altogether a bad practice...